# How to build MXNET custom operators into separate library/package with C++?

Tags: c++, mxnet

I want to try out some new activation functions and I have successfully created custom operators in C++ on top of the latest mxnet source code. But what I really like to have is to build a separate library (.so file in ubuntu) just for my custom operators so I can leave mxnet source code and its library as it is and I do not have to worry about merging my code to mxnet source code every time I need to use newer mxnet releases. I understand that if this is working, I need both libmxnet.so and mycustom.so in order to use my new activation functions. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An activation function that is useful for your neural net is probably going to be useful for others. Why not submit a pull request, and have it merged into the repo?

Comment: I can think of many reasons why it would be impractical to deploy custom operators in the official library: the code may not be production ready, it might not be generally useful enough to justify bloating the main distribution, it might contain proprietary code or code issued under a conflicting license (e.g. GPL), etc.

Comment: There exists an issue: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/9547

Answer (score 1):

As Tauran pointed out, this is currently not possible. An feature request has been created: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/9547 and it would be a good idea to subscribe to that and upvote it if you haven't done so already. :)